# How to sort an array of array based on a id

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How to sort an array of array-based on id. This is how the Input is

```
[ 
    [ { id: 14},{ id: 15},{ id: 17} ],
    [ { id: 4},{ id: 71} ], 
    [ { id: 25},{ id: 26},{ id: 27},{ id: 28} ]
]
```

And this is the expected output

```
[
    [ { id: 4},{ id: 71} ], 
    [ { id: 14},{ id: 15},{ id: 17} ], 
    [ { id: 25},{ id: 26},{ id: 27},{ id: 28} ]
]
```

Comment: Are the internal arrays already sorted?

Comment: how will we compare two internal arrays?

Comment: good question. yes they are sorted

Comment: I gave a downvote as you did not include any attempt to solve this yourself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming that **`your internal arrays already sorted`**  and you **`want to sort array items based on the first object`** , you can do this.

```js
const data = [ 
    [ { id: 14},{ id: 15},{ id: 17} ],
    [ { id: 4},{ id: 71} ], 
    [ { id: 25},{ id: 26},{ id: 27},{ id: 28} ]
];

data.sort((a, b) => a[0].id - b[0].id);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do that.

```js
const your_array = [ 
    [ { id: 14},{ id: 15},{ id: 17} ],
    [ { id: 4},{ id: 71} ], 
    [ { id: 25},{ id: 26},{ id: 27},{ id: 28} ]
];
your_array.sort((x, y) => x[0].id - y[0].id);
console.log(your_array);
```

Comment: What does this answer make difference with [Mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66039234/9071943) and [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66039236/9071943)?

Comment: I was already in the state of writing the code. When i submitted i saw your answer.